# TableView with bar to change content on top, how to build it?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have to build a tableView with a top bar "slider" like the one in the youtube app in the picture below.

I just wanted to ask if it's better to:

- Use just one tableView and switch the content by changing some switches in the delegates methods and reloading all the rows

or

- Use two tableViews and hide the one that's not displayed

If none of the two methods above is the best one please point me in the right direction, thank you.

[image: Example image]

Comment: One tableView , reload is best..!! In my view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1 :

Take a `UISegmentView` on the top and have a single `UITableView`. Change the content of `UITableView` on valueChange event of segment.

Option 2 :

Have look at this awesome library by Yalantis - [**Segmentio**](https://github.com/Yalantis/Segmentio). I have myself used this on couple of occasions. Handy when you have to horizontally scroll the segments (exactly what you need in your case). You can have a single `UITableView` for this as well.

Option 3 :

Check out another useful library by Yalantis - [**Persei**](https://github.com/Yalantis/Persei). Just hard scroll the table to see these options. Again, single `UITableView`.

In all, the best solution, in my opinion is to have a single `UITableView`. Working with multiple tableView might seem a clean way for a start, but trust me, maintainability is the key and having a single `UITableView` would be a better approach.